# Convert string format 08:30 to float 8.5

Tags: c#

I believe that there is some similar topic about this, but I really go too far and I do not see where I'm currently wrong, I want to get from the textbox where it's shown at 8:30, the float value is 8.5.

I always get a value of 8.3 for 8:30.
This is my current code, please correct me where I'm wrong.

```
var value = _event.EventText; // 08:18:00\ntekst!"
    timeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(split[0]);
    textBoxSaldo.Text = timeSpan.ToString("hh':'mm");

    CultureInfo ci = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
    ci.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ":";
    float saldo = float.Parse(textBoxSaldo.Text, NumberStyles.Any, ci);
```

[image]

Thanks to everyone for help

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly these numbers mean? For example, are you trying to format 8 minutes 30 seconds (or 8 hours 30 minutes) as 8.5 hours/8.5 minutes?

Comment: So `8:30` is a time value that you want to express as a float value that represents the hours?

Comment: You seem to by trying to parse a time value as a currency.

Comment: @ZoharPeled 08:30 is the time I got before in the regex.

Comment: in the tektboku balance I set the time from the time frame under this format, I added the above question.

Comment: Use TimeSpan.TryParse()

Comment: `TimeSpan.Parse("8:30").TotalHours`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```cs
double saldo = TimeSpan.Parse(textBoxSaldo.Text).TotalHours;
```

**EDIT**

Or with validity checks, like in [Zohar Peled's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56564736/10380786)

Comment: Never trust user input. A code that use `Parse` instead of `TryParse` on a user-supplied value does not belong in a production environment.

Answer (score 1):

If `08:30` represents a time of day value, the easiest conversion to a float representing the hours would be to use `TimeSpan`:

```
if(TimeSpan.TryParse(textBoxSaldo.Text, out TimeSpan ts))
{
    var saldo = ts.TotalHours;
}
else
{
    // show an error message to the client.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
public static void Main()
{
    string input = "8:30";
    float output = ParseTimeAsDecimal(input);
    Console.WriteLine(output);
}

public static float ParseTimeAsDecimal(string time)
{
    DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(time, "H:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    int hours = d.Hour;
    int minutes = d.Minute;
    float minutesFraction = minutes / 60f;
    return ((float)hours) + minutesFraction;
}
```

Input: 8:30

Output: 8.5

Answer (score 0):

Below method may not fancy but you can try:

1. Get text from textbox, your string will have format x:y
2. Split string in step 1 by `string.split(':')`
3. convert x and y from  split string in step 2 to float (y = split[1] / 60)
4. saldo = x + y